# What are TVarData.Reserved fields used for in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, variant

There are 3 word-sized reserved fields in Delphi 7 TVarData record type, and a fourth pointer-sized reserved field in Delphi XE2 TLargestVarData record type.
Can I use at least one of them for data storage, or it is strictly prohibited and unsafe?

Comment: For sure it's very bad practice to use reserved from someone else data structures for your needs. Documentation says they are "unused" but after all you put your source code at high risk.

Comment: It's just like a reservation in a restaurant: you can try it, but don't be surprised once trouble hits you.

Comment: *Reserved* means "this is reserved for some future use", and no, you should not use it, because it's **reserved**. Some future version may use it, and your code will either be broken or you'll introduce impossible-to-debug issues. If it's marked specifically as not being available, leave it alone.